# Difference between 'created by' and 'created from'

Tags: american-english

I am writing an essay and I was stuck in the middle of it because I was wondering if I should use from or by in this sentence:

'Incapable to detect that his own circumstances are ***created by/from*** his inability to see and act based on reality,~~~ (I have to continue)'

Should I use by or from?

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192036/from-vs-by

Answer (score 3):

There is a **subtle** difference between "created by" and "created from" in your sentence.

- Created from his inability.... His circumstances had their origins at his inability...
- Created by his inability....   His inability created the circumstances.

Your choice depends on **which meaning you want to emphasize**, "the origin" or "the action".

> "created by" - "All those problems were created by him." (He created all those problems)
>
> "created from" - "Several countries were created from the Ottoman Empire."
> "A park was created from part of the old farm."